# WinForms application crashes on startup

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, visual-studio-2019, legacy

I have very big and complex legacy application made in WinForms. I build it successfully using .NET Reactor. After setup build, I install it and it doesn't start. I looked in Task manager/Processes and it is running for few seconds and then crashes.

Event logger: System.File.IO exception.

So it can't find some file (probably .dll) it uses.

I need advice how to trace that file.

Comment: Did you try to run source code from IDE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866879/diagnosing-a-file-not-found-error-in-a-net-application

Comment: Yes, I runned source code from IDE and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Clearly you need to improve the exception reporting, so you can see what file is missing.  Exception.ToString() tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Fuslog Assembly Binding Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer).

You can set it up to log attempted assembly bindings so that you can see where your application is trying to read which assemblies from .

This should hopefully help you identify what is missing.

**NB:** To start the Fuslog viewer, you'll need to call `fuslogvw` from an *administrator* developer command prompt. If you don't start it as an administrator, the settings (shown below) will not be editable, and you won't be able to provide your own custom log path.

[image]